# how Live data will be update in MVVM

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I want to get input from the user using EditText and pass it to server and show the response to the user. I do this simply without any architecture but I would like to implement it in MVVM.
this is my repository code:

```
class Repository {

    fun getData(context: Context, word: String): LiveData<String> {

        val result = MutableLiveData<String>()

        val request = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST,
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
            Response.Listener {
                result.value = it.toString()
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                result.value = it.toString()
            }) 
            {
                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params["word"] = word
                    return params
                }
            }

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        queue.add(request)

        return result
    }
}
```

and these are my View Model codes:

```
class ViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun getData(word: String): LiveData<String> {
        val repository = Repository()
        return repository.getData(getApplication(), word)
    }
}
```

and my mainActivity would be like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)

        model.getData("test").observe(this, Observer {
            Log.i("Log", "activity $it")
        })
    }
}
```

My layout has an EditText which I want to get user input and pass it to the server, how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here how i did it in my projet.

You can probably use android annotations.
It's gonna requiere you to put some dependencies and maybe change the class a bit, but then you gonna link your Viewmodel with your repository and then you gonna have to program the setter of the variable to do a notifyChange() by making the class herited from BaseObservable. Then in the xml, if you did the  correctly, you should be able to do a thing like text:"@={model.variable}" and it should be updating at the same time.

A bit hard and explain or to show for me sorry, but i would look into Android Annotations with @DataBinding, @DataBound :BaseObservable 
https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Data-binding-support

Hope that can help a bit!